# How to let game characters enter existing 3D buildings model in my own game?

Tags: models, 3dsmax

I want to use ShiVa 3D game engine to build a 3D RPG game. And I want to load other people's 3D models into my game so that I wouldn't need to draw these things myself.

Here's a building model I loaded in 3ds Max, I don't know if I loaded this model in game engine, can my character enter this building and see the decoration inside? How can I verify this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4MXB.png

And if I cannot let my character enter this building, is there any resources that I can use on the Internet?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading 3D models is a pretty standard feature of game engines, and any engine worth its salt will be able to load at least a few formats, whether or not it is a proprietary format, or a common format such as 3DS/FBX/MB. Check the documentation you have for loading static geometry, and what formats are supported. The biggest issue you will have is going to be collision mesh generation. Depending on what your engine supports, it may load the entire model as one large object, and generate a single collision primitive for the entire building, at which point walking inside it wouldn't work. If the parsing system loads and generates the building on a per object basis, then you can get the ability to enter the building. This is also dependent on how the model was constructed in the editor (3ds max/maya/etc).

Comment: Thanks. So if I want to let my character walking inside, I need to know how the engine parse the model and how the model be constructed. I can go check how the engine parse the model, but I don't know how to verify how the model was constructed. Can you tell me how? Thanks~

Comment: Load up the model file within the editing program it was made in, and check to see if the entire model has been packaged as a single object, or if it is broken out into many different pieces. If you aren't working directly with an artists, this can be an inconvenient process to find models that are built for your intended purpose.

Comment: Thank you! I loaded the building mentioned in my question in 3ds Max, and I can delete some part of the model(till the floor left), this means the model is somewhat on a per object basis, right?
And I have looked up all my resources but couldn't find how to see the configurations of ShiVa 3D game engine, do you know how to check this? 
Thanks a lot, really!!!

Comment: I don't know anything about the engine itself, but the documentation that talks about static geometry and collision meshes should provide some indication as to how the engine handles it. If not, you will just have to play around with it and see what you can get.